# replacing one word with the same word twice in unix

Tags: unix

how can i convert "some text run_id = one number some text" to some_text run_id between one number and one number some text

for example i want to convert xyz run_id = 1 to run_id between 1 and 1. And in this text 1 is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/run_id = \([[:digit:]]\+\)/run_id between \1 and \1/g'
```

That uses `\(` and `\)` as capturing parentheses. A
demo

```
sed 's/run_id = \([[:digit:]]\+\)/run_id between \1 and \1/g' <<END
some text run_id = 1234 some text
END
```

```
some text run_id between 1234 and 1234 some text
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!